# how to put fb share thumbnail to left

Tags: facebook-share

I want share layout is "thumbnail on left."

I check youtube url: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i5XZH7jeDiQ&feature=youtu.be&list=RDqIoDWTF0qSo

It's og:image is "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/i5XZH7jeDiQ/hqdefault.jpg", the size is 480x360

share layout is "thumbnail on left. And description on right."

but in my website. My og:image is also 480x360...

and I share my page, in pc fb, share layout is "thumbnail on top. And description on bottom..."

why? my og:type is video too...

How to put thumbnail to left on share block in pc fb ?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use a smaller image.

The minimum size for the Facebook share og:image is **600x315**. Keep in mind to maintain an aspect ratio of **1.91:1**.

You can debug your open graph meta tags in [Facebook Sharing debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/).

Comment: But why youtube share layout is thumbnail on left? We also use 480x360 image size.

Comment: Probably, because that is a small image and the only image that Facebook page parser could find in the page.

Comment: But I use fb sharing debug, it's show they get og:image and it size is 480x360.
example: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DI7ffDXEMcxA%26index%3D21%26list%3DRDqIoDWTF0qSo